# Electronic pacts

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

Demon the Descent suggest that pacts must exist on something that'll have at least some level of permanence, a pact can not be written in wet sand. It suggest several mediums such as paper, and flesh, with either ink or blood working. I did not see it reference electronics. Would having a document signed on a tablet work, for example? If it works what happens when a copy is made? To destroy the contract would you have to destroy all copies?

Comment: You should probably split this into two questions, since copies can be made of physical documents as well.

Comment: @WesleyObenshain maybe, but I imagine that the nature of a pact means that only the original signature matters, the thing with an electronic signature is that there would be no difference between a copy and the original.

Comment: Sure there are. Any number that don't include metaphysics.

Comment: still it seems like physical copies would be a completely separate subject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electronic documents don't have the necessary permanence. Think about it this way: If you're working on a document in Microsoft Word and the power to your computer is cut off, what happens to it?

There isn't a physical copy of the document if it's electronic. It's all electrons flowing back and forth, and the specific electrons don't stick around for long.

Comment: as a software engineer that says more about Word, and that OS that can run it, than electronic documents in general... but point taken

Comment: I was trying to use an example that would reach the most people... Your point is also taken and fully agreed with. ^_^

Comment: If the data existed only in RAM, you might be able to make that argument, but any saved data still creates a physical copy. If you're using a magnetic drive, that physical copy is stored in the form of a magnetically aligned ceramic disc covered with a ferrous layer.